# bootstrap navbar wide logo issue - prevent wrapping

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

I encountered a problem in my navbar logo which is `330px` wide.
When the browser resizes to mobile the hamburger menu goes to the next line, but what I want to achieve is when it reach to specific size the logo will shrink but it turns out the hamburger menu goes to the next line. here's my sample fiddle: [CODEPLY](https://www.codeply.com/p/lDRI4EFDcY)

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/330x50?text=Logo" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I already update the post. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by adding flex-nowrap to the navbar > container...

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
  <div class="container flex-nowrap">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/330x50?text=Logo" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

https://codeply.com/p/owHqM5pWe6

***EDIT***

Per the comment with flex-nowrap, it would be better to warp the brand and toggler in a single flexbox div with flex-nowrap...

```
  <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap w-100">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/330x50?text=Logo" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  </div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/owHqM5pWe6

Comment: Thank you! im new in using bootstrap

Comment: oh by the way... I encountered another problem.. since its already a flex-wrap when I clicked the hamburger menu, the menus moved in a different location.